# vite plugin to return the source code of the vue component

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm building a UI Tool for myself using Vue3 and Vite2. And I got a simple demo page like this:

```
<template>
  <Switch v-model:value="bool" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Switch from "../lib/Switch.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Switch,
  },
  setup() {
    const bool = ref(false);
    return {
      bool,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

now I want to render this source code to the page. Is there anyway I can do it using vite and its plugins?

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about

Comment: Define "source code". You can open your DOM inspect (browser devtools). If you want something static, you'll need to use SSR or SSG with a solution like Nuxt (if you are right clicking on `View page source`).